# Multithreading in python - Blocking call running in background

Tags: python, multithreading, udp

I've been recently working on a program (as you may be able to see from my previous question asked) and I've been having real trouble in understanding and implementing multithreading.

I followed a tutorial ([binary tides](http://www.binarytides.com/python-socket-programming-tutorial/2/)) for setting up a UDP server, which works great. The issue I am having however, is that when I create a blocking UDP socket on a new thread, the code which I have in my main program where I initially created the thread doesn't work. Here is some of my code:

main.py:

```
from thread import*
import connections


start_new_thread(networkStart.startConnecton())
print 'This should print!'
```

networkStart.py:

```
def startConnecton():
    userData.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)  
    print 'Socket created'
    try:
        userData.s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    except socket.error, msg:
        print 'Bind failed. Error code: ' +str(msg[0]) + 'Message' +msg[1]
        sys.exit()
    print 'Socket bind complete'
    userData.s.listen(10) 
    # Set the socket to listening mode, if there are more than 10 connections waiting reject the rest
    print 'Socket now listening' 
    #Function for handling connections. Each new connection is handled on a separate thread
    start_new_thread(connections.connectionListen())
```

connections.py:

```
def connectionListen():
    while 1:
            print 'waiting for connection'
            #wait to accept a connection - blocking call
            conn, addr = userData.s.accept()
            userData.clients += 1
            print 'Connected with ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1])
            #start new thread takes 1st argument as a function name to be run, second is the tuple of arguments 
            start_new_thread(users.clientthread ,(conn, userData.clients))
```

I basically just want to be able to execute any code in main.py after the startConnection function is called on a new thread (i.e, print the string in this instance).

I've been struggling with this program for quite a while, Python is new to me and I'm finding it quite challenging. I'm assuming I must be making some errors in the way i've implemented multithreading, any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Is this the full code? What errors do you get? The call to `start_new_thread` looks invalid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`start_new_thread` receives a function and an arguments list, but you are using directly the function call: `start_new_thread(networkStart.startConnecton())`.

However, I recommend you to use the `threading` module ([the official documentation does so](http://docs.python.org/2/library/thread.html)), which has a higher level of abstraction.

```
import threading
import connections

threading.Thread(target=networkStart.startConnecton).start()
print 'This should print!'
```